# Importing Data from Excel to Sharepoint (External Data field)

Tags: powershell, bcs, external-content-type, external-data

I have a list containing external data columns. I have an excel file that has values for external data columns. I want to bulk update via Powershell. When I try to update the value from excel to SharePoint, the value is displayed in the display form, but not in the edit form. When I click the external data value in the display form, it shows an error as "The passed in identifier is not properly encoded."

I am not able to find any relevant material for this.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though your external list has only been configured to display external data, not update it via the SharePoint UI.

[External content types in SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/general-development/external-content-types-in-sharepoint)